# What's the recommended browser for Confluence?

Tags: browser, confluence

Is there a browser that supports all the Confluence features best?

I know that IE doesn' support Drag and Drop, but what about other features?

Comment: I believe Chrome and Firefox both support all of Confluence's features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As webwesen's answer says, all browsers listed on the supported platforms doc should be usable with Confluence.

My personal experience is that using Chrome is a good bet, since most of the Confluence development team uses Chrome day-to-day (or at least they did when I was in the Confluence team). However, Chrome doesn't have a built-in WebDAV client which means that Confluence's Edit-In-Office features do not work.  If this is important to you, then I'd suggest Firefox with the [Office Connector Add-on](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Installing+the+Firefox+Add-On+for+the+Office+Connector) installed.

Comment: We don't use the Office connector (yet), so thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

check https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Supported+Platforms
scroll down to "web browsers - desktop"

Comment: That's only the list of supported browsers, but I don't see a recommendation for any of them.

Comment: I's suggest that the recommended browsers are any in that page that say "Latest stable version supported" -- i.e. modern browsers that are not Internet Explorer ;)